# How to use relative line numbering universally in Vim

Tags: configuration, vim

I love the relative line numbering feature in Vim 7.3, but am having trouble making it stick universally. For many files, line numbering reverts to absolute mode, even though I have specified:

```
set rnu
```

in my `.vimrc` file. Any idea what could be causing this? I am using Vim 7.3 on OSX 10.6, with the Janus package of extensions.

Comment: That's odd. Do you notice absolute line numbering only for certain file types? Check for occurrences of `set number` or `set nu` in your `.vimrc` and all loaded scripts (`:scriptnames`).

Comment: Correct. For some files, e.g. .csv, it does absolute numbering, while for most it does relative, as I specified. I have a lot of scripts loaded via Janus, so I may have to sift through them to see what might be toggling this.

Comment: put this as an issue on the github repo: https://github.com/carlhuda/janus/issues/472

Answer (score 5):

Try using `:verbose set rnu?` and `:verbose set nu?` to find the script that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your `.vimrc.after`:

> set nonumber
>
> set relativenumber

Relative line numbers should persist with these settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `set rnu` at the very end of your .vimrc. Relative numbering is mutually exclusive with absolute numbering. I suspect Janus is trying to be smart and sets absolute numbering for some filetypes.

Comment: Filetype events are launched after vimrc was already sourced, so it does not matter where you will put this line if you put it in the vimrc and it is reset on filetype event.

Comment: Note that as of Vim version 7.3.1115 the `'number'` and `'relativenumber'` settings are no longer mutually exclusive, they can now be set independently.